# Difference between "Latest version" and "Lastest version"

Tags: meaning, grammar

I see some deveeloper use "Lastest version" but almost other user "Latest version"

Comment: 'Lastest' is not a word. It's either an error or a jokey attempt to coin a new word.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Sounds precious.

Comment: "Latest version" = "last version" perhaps.  But, as noted, lastest is no good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**Lastest**" is not a proper word.
"**Latest**" version means the *last* version that was released till now.